# Как совместить angular и stylelint?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Всем привет.Как объединить angular 4 и https://stylelint.io/ правильно? 
Вот я стартанул новый проект через ng new my-app и как туда добавить линтер? 
Воспользовался вот этим путем https://stylelint.io/user-guide/node-api/

Package.json выглядит вот так

```js
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "licd nt": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "slint": "stylelint './**/*.css' --syntax css --config .stylelintrc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "stylelint": "^8.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }

}
```

Правила в файле .stylelinrc

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "indentation": 2,
    "string-quotes": "single",
    "no-duplicate-selectors": true
  }
}
```

Запускаю командой npm run slint

В консоли выводится вот что

> my-app@0.0.0 slint C:\Users\asalamatin\Desktop\angular\my-app
>   stylelint './**/*.css' --syntax css --config .stylelintrc

И все. Никаких ошибок не отображается, хотя в css файле их специально допускаю.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать что-то вроде:

```
"slint": "stylelint --syntax scss \"./**/**/*.scss\""
```